How can I reach a spot on the side of my house directly above an outdoor A/C unit?
I need to reach a spot where a woodpecker pecked holes on an outside corner post of my house about 14-15 feet off the ground. The problem is the spot is directly above where my AC unit sits, so there's not a good place to put the ladder.


If I put the ladder next to the AC unit (on the concrete side, not the grass), I can't really reach the spot (it would probably be a good 4 feet to the right of the ladder).

There's about 1-2 feet of space between the AC unit and the wall, which would not provide enough angle to get 15 feet up.

The grassy side of the wall (where the downspout is) is too uneven and steep to support an extension ladder, and I haven't seen a multi-purpose ladder at the store that would be tall enough to place on the hill but still allow me to reach 15 ft up. Even if such a tall multipurpose ladder existed, it would likely be way too expensive.

I briefly looked into moving the AC unit but that doesn't seem like a realistic option. (A quick search suggests an HVAC company would have to come out and move it and that could cost around $1000.)


The only option that I feel could be feasible is to place an extension ladder far enough away from the wall and AC unit so that it would clear the top of the AC unit. The problem with this is that that would make a very shallow angle between the ground and base of the ladder, and there would be risk of it sliding out... not to mention the top of the ladder would just be leaning against the wall.
Any ideas on how I can safely reach this spot? I don't mind investing in practical tools that could be reasonably useful in the future (like a 24-ft extension ladder), but I'm not going to spend hundreds or thousands of dollars just to fix like $30 worth of woodpecker damage.
I've also thought about hiring out a contractor to fix this for me, but not sure even who I would call for this. A siding company?
Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

forget about moving AC, rent a scaffold

Hate to say it, but the woodpecker might be going for bugs, which might mean you have more than a $30 problem.

Huh?  A ladder is going to have to be a 4:1 hypoentuse ratio, which should easily clear the A/C.

Moving the AC around is not practical
You could rent a scaffolding for about $100 a day.
Then build it up around and above the AC.
If it is a 15 foot scaffold then with you standing on it, you can reach 21 feet high.

Found at Home Depo

Scaffold rental is super cheap. The expensive part is the transport. If you have a truck, you could pick up scaffolding from a local rental shop. But if you have a truck, it's cheaper just to park it sideways right there in front of the a/c and put the extension ladder resting inside of the bed, against the side so that it does not move. I do this frequently, when extending extension ladders high up, to give extra stability.
Another option I've used is to drive stakes on the ground to keep the extension ladder from slipping back. That way you can have a low angle on the ladder.
About the ladder resting on the siding, just get a couple ladder mitts (also called ladder bumbers). They protect the siding and give extra grip.
By all means, invest in a harness and lanyard and use it.

If it was my place, I would possibly temporarily take out the grass at the side as well as enough dirt so that there is an area the same elevation as whatever the A/C is sitting on.  Now with both sides of the A/C level, I might place sawhorses on both sides as the base on which to make a platform - perhaps a 4/8 sheet of plywood and - get a 2x6 to put under it in front of the A/C unit - screw that 2x6 to the sheet of plywood in several places otherwise that plywood is going to 'smile' as in not be straight across when  weight is on it. (probably 3/4 inch CD - it needs to be sturdy thus 3/4 inch but cheap this CD instead of A/C.  Now with such a platform I'd use a ladder to reach the area.  That's just approximately something I've done in the past. I'm not qualified to recommend a solution, I'm simply recalling something I did years ago to reach an otherwise unreachable place on my front porch.

Rent a boom-type manlift. That's the easy and safe approach.
Depending on your local market it may not even cost much more than renting staging (which is more time consuming to put up and may require earthmoving to set safely), and is all-but-certainly cheaper than the trip to the hospital when a poorly placed ladder or staging set badly turns out to be a bad choice.
Do read and respect the operating limits for the lift, of course.

Hire a scaffold from a tool hire place
Or if you're into sketchy and your AC unit is bolted down, use the extension ladder but tie the bottom of the ladder to the base of the AC unit so that it can't slide away,  use 2 ropes.
